# CMD: Bat to Exe Converter - Temp directory problem

Tags: windows, cmd, exe, converters, batch-file

i am using ['Bat to Exe Converter'](http://www.f2ko.de/English/b2e/index.php) to convert my batch files to exe format.

Now, i am running into some problems.
Whenever i convert something, and i set 'Working Directory' to 'Current Directory', and i start my exe in `echo on` mode, this is what i end up with to check if there is a specific file in the directory of my exe:

`the actual command: if not exist "%~dp0\file.txt" goto :nofile`

`output: if not exist "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\4CBC\\file.txt" goto :nofile`

Can anyone help me with this? I don't want it in the temp directory, i want it to be in the directory of my exe.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Without having *Bat to Exe* changed by the author, I think you have two options:

1. Remove the need for accessing %~dp0

   Perhaps you can merge `file.txt` with the include option of *Bat to Exe* into the EXE   file. If so, `"file.txt"` will automatically be unpacked in the current directory when running your compiled exe, and you can it access by `%CD%\file.txt`.
2. Get `%~dp0` from outside and pass it to the exe as a command line parameter.

   This can be done by a simple starter `bat` file that resides in the same directory as your compiled main batch file. This script schould contain the line

   ```
   YourCompiled.Exe %~dp0% %%*
   ```

   Your compiled exe then gets its directory from %1. So you cannot pack everything into one exe, but the main portion of it, perhaps that is sufficient for you.

Comment: problem with the 1st one: the 'file.txt' is created by the batch file when the user enters an option. The file has to go with the batch file all the time. And, when it is merged, and you exit the batch just with the 'exit' button; it actually does not merge it again; it just leaves it there.

Comment: Well, then the 2nd alternative might be an option for you. Or, if you think you really need everything in one EXE file, did you consider using a "real" compiled language?

Comment: the 2nd one seems useful. is it possible to get another variable of it %2 or something like that? %1 is already assigned to do something else with it.

Comment: Well, you can try either YourCompiled.Exe %%* %~dp0%  or YourCompiled.Exe %1 %~dp0%

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently your batch to exe converter simply packs the batch file and extracts it to a temporary directory prior to execution. Very simplistic, hard to get wrong (compared to actually understand the batch file) but it introduces errors such as the one you're describing.

Your best bet is probably to use another batch to exe converter; some of them are actually a little more sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this is not a good idea. firstly, its prone to errors and instability of the converter on different cmd features. secondly, a determined hacker can still decode what you are doing with the batch. My suggestion, if you are so afraid of people looking into your batch,

```
1) let only the people who are authorized to use your batch to use it
2) give them the correct permissions.
```

OR, don't use batch at all

```
1) create a central interface such as a web interface, where all tasks to be done goes through that interface, like using an ATM machine where only buttons are allowed and all the available user options can be done by pushing buttons...etc..
2) authenticate your users through a central authentication system, eg Active Directory, or LDAP or a database.
```

Comment: it's not that i don't like guys looking into my code: it's just that you can assign stuff way better if it's an exe.

Answer (score 0):

*This is an 2.5 yr old subject but there is an answer to this so I'm posting for anyone else that happens to find this in a search.*

---

[B2EC written by Fatih Kodak](http://www.f2ko.de/), has an option to "Submit current directory".

When this is used, you can reference %1 in your batch file to get the path of the EXE that was executed (instead of the path of the extracted BAT that is really being run).

[image]

Hovering over that option in the UI shows "Submit the current working directory as the last parameter".  The "last parameter" in my use has always been %1 but you can test your code to be sure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The latest version, 2.1.4 at time of writing, of Bat to Exe by Fatih Kodak creates an Environmental Variable at runtime that can be substituted in place of %~dp0 to reference the Exe's path. Therefore, you can simply replace %-dp0 with %b2eprogrampathname% in the original batch file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use external folders with f2ko's batch to exe converter.  Having
a separate folder for subroutines can neaten up a project folder.
To call mysubroutine that is located in mysubroutinesfolder\mysubroutine,

```
...
pushd mysubroutinesfolder
call mysubroutine
popd
...
```

The call can be made a one liner:

```
call xqt mysubroutine
```

where xqt.cmd is a program that does the call for you:

```
pushd mysubroutinesfolder
call %*
popd
exit /b
```

(the %* means "all of the arguments").
In this way your batch programs run as batch, and UNMODIFIED they will
compile with the bat to exe converter, creating a completely folder independent executable.  Select "temporary directory",
and include all of the subroutines/executables in your mysubroutines folder
by "selecting them all" with your cursor as usual, then hit "copy".
Be sure to include the xqt.cmd program too; place it "outside" of your mysubroutines folder.  Make sure that is is accessible by your main program.  Remember to select x64 if you
are runnning on a x64 machine, or the executable will not find SYSTEM32
files.  You can find f2k0's batch to exe converter at:

http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?pid=b2e

Answer (score 0):

Try this development environment for batch scripts, **[Batch Compiler](http://bc.gotek.info)** . It has everything you need to develop a batch program.And compile into stable stand alone executable (Exe).

```
Friendly user interface.
Debugger, Check your code for syntax errors.
Powerful, versatile compiler.
Allows mouse input in batch files.
Use Windows Common Dialog Boxes.(BrowseFiles,BrowseFolders)
Draw graphics in batch files.
Reverse engineering proof encryption of source code.
Include Company name, Copyright info and Version info.
Make invisible(silent) executables.
Executables with administrator privileges.
Run & debug your script while editing.
Embed resources with executable.(music,images,files)
Advance Commands (BrowseFiles,LaunchSilent,MouseCMD)
Stand-alone executables.No dependencies needed.
Executables are woking on almost all windows operating systems.(98 to 10)
```

Quick download : http://bc.gotek.info/files/BatchCompiler159.zip

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Use `%CD%` instead of `%~dp0`.

**EDIT:**

B2EC is not a real converter. Creation location of equipped .cmd file was chosen to be `%TEMP%` and this is a good choice. Application just lacks 3rd option for working directory of the script - .exe file directory. I advise you to mail the author about adding this one.

Different paths for .exe and created .cmd lead to information loss, i.e. we are unable to know .exe directory and current directory at the same time without providing additional information to the script (e.g. using environment variable or passing it as first/last argument to the script). This script would need to handle it and we would end writing cmd scripts tailored for this converter, which is bad.

`%~dp0` - script directory (`%TEMP%/.../`) - practically useless

`%cd%` - working directory (as set up in the converter) - currently there are only 2 options: current directory (working directory of .exe) and temporary directory (actually equal to `%~dp0`, but without trailing backslash)

I think it can be solved by patching `cmd.exe` instance in memory to change the script path, but that's B2EC developer's duty.

Side note: Normal executable files can be easily executed with specified 0th argument by providing appriopriate `lpApplicationName` and `lpCommandLine` to `CreateProcess` function. Command files are executed via `cmd.exe`, so 0th argument cannot be set this way.

Comment: cd shows again 'the working directory', not the directory of the file itself.

Comment: Actually it shows current directory if you have chosen working directory to be the current directory (which is the default option). This converter isn't a real converter, because it just creates .bat/.cmd file in `%TEMP%` directory and that's why `%~X0` doesn't work as you want.

Comment: i tried it out, and it seems it still gives the working directory, so for example if a file exe file is located in "MyUser/Desktop/test.exe", and i run it on the commandline from "C:\Users\MyUser", the working directory is still 'MyUser'. I want it to be the location of the file, so 'MyUser/Desktop'!

Answer (score -1):

%cd% will give you the current directory:

```
if not exist "%CD%\file.txt" goto :nofile
```

Comment: cd shows again 'the working directory', not the directory of the file itself.